# BIND9 response depending on server network card

Tags: networking, dns, debian, bind9

i have 3 virtual machines running on debian 8 on a private network. Let's name them A, B and C. 
=> C is a virtual machine with 2 network cards (we name them a and b) each network card having a different IP adress. There is BIND9 installed on the C server. 
=> A server has his DNS set on the IP of the a network card 
=> B server has his DNS set on the IP of the b network card
How can i adapt the DNS server response depending on the asked network card, and what is the best way to do that ? 
Thank you in advance !

EDIT :

```
# named.example01.conf

acl trusted { 192.168.7.0/24; localhost; };
acl guest   { 192.168.8.0/24; };

view trusted {
   match-clients { trusted; };

   allow-recursion { any; };

   zone "myzone.example" {
     type master;
     file "db.myzone.example";
   };
   zone "7.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
     type master;
     file "db.192.168.7";
   };
};

view guest {
   match-clients { guest; };

   allow-recursion { any; };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `view` with `match-destinations` statement.

Comment: I didn't find doc about match-detinations, but about match_client. Does this redirect a group of ip/adress to a zone ?
See my edit, couldn't include code here

Comment: Well, I see in manual together `match-cliens` and `match-destinations`, for example: http://www.csd.uwo.ca/staff/magi/doc/bind9/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#AEN3035 But have you tried adding `match-destinations { ip-network-card; };` statements to your views? Does it work or are there any errors?

Comment: Just tried it. It's working perfectly with the match_clients. I also tried with match-destinations. I had no errors, but it didn't seem to work. But thank you anyway, you helped me to resolve my issue :) !!!